# Detect amount of weight on Android device screen

Tags: android, api, scale

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting the pressure with which a button gets pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220554/getting-the-pressure-with-which-a-button-gets-pressed)

The only type of pressure function I've been able to find measure sea level pressure. I haven't been able to find any API that could do this. But I have found several apps in the market that act as scalers for....illicit substances. Nontheless I'd like to know how to achieve this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is only possible on some devices and with very low accuracy. `MotionEvent`'s [`getPressure()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getPressure()) method was meant to determine just this; however it depends solely on the accuracy, calibration, and feature set (some devices will always say `1`) of the target device:

> The pressure generally ranges from 0 (no pressure at all) to 1 (normal pressure), however values higher than 1 may be generated depending on the calibration of the input device.
>
> -- *[Developer Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getPressure(int))*

Some devices also register a [tool type](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getToolType(int)), which may have different pressures relative to what you might expect. It is far from saying "2lbs of pressure from metal object".

It is also worth noting that this only works for a touch event (`MotionEvent`)--putting something, like a wad of paper, which does not register a touch event, would not show any pressure at all.